# Answers to interactive Python-Think Like a COmputer scientists?

Tags: python, computer-science

Im a begginer in Python and I want to learn more by practicing the exercises
There are lots of exercises in Python but when I'm stuck on a exercise I dont know who to turn
to when I get lost and confused.

For ex, one pf the functions im having trouble with is:

Write a fruitful function sumTo(n) that returns the sum of all integer numbers up to and including n. So sumTo(10) would be 1+2+3...+10 which would return the value 55. Use the equation (n * (n + 1)) / 2.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What are you having trouble with specifically?  The question pretty much tells you exactly what to write.  Are you unfamiliar with the syntax you use to create functions or something?

Answer (score 3):

I am not an experienced programmer myself but I guess the following code snippet should work just fine.

```
def sumTo(n):
    return (n * (n + 1)/2)
```

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't seem to be a question in there.

Using your equation;

```
def sumTo(n):
    return (n*(n+1)/2)
```

In answer to your function, Python has some excellent functions;

```
def sumTo(n):
    # This will create a list of numbers from 0 to n
    # e.g. range(0, 11) = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    list_of_all_integers = range(0, n+1)
    # The sum does exactly what you think it does, adds them all together.
    return sum(list_of_all_integers)
```

If you are looking for places to learn Python there are lots of interactive ones online

- [Learn Python](http://www.learnpython.org/)
- [Code Academy](http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/python)